# Changing FORM element values with JavaScript only works once

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The following function to change the text of an input box works perfectly. but when I try and fire it again with a different parameter, it does not change.

```
function changeForm(name)
{
    $("#the-input-box").val(name);
}
```

This also happens when I try change the selectedIndex on a select tag.

Also, the form is located on a modal box using Twitter's bootstrap, could that be the issue?

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you firing it? Could we see a little more code, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way you are using the modal box.  I've experienced the exact same thing before.

The thing about the `id` attribute is that there can only be **ONE** at any given time within the HTML DOM.

You may want to check whether you are 'destroying' your modal box after closing it.  The first time you open the modal box, calling the function works without any problems.  There could be a chance that after opening the modal box again, the function doesn't work anymore.  This is because you are spawning multiple instances of the modal box and this causes multiple instances of #the-input-box to appear in the DOM.

Give that a try and let me know.  The key is to **DESTROY** the modal box when it is closed (maybe closing it is fine, but I prefer the more drastic approach of destroying).